# How does frictional force push when we walk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Friction is due to the attractive force between the body and the surface so how does it push us forward when we walk or in a bicycle

Comment: Friction comes from the formation of molecular bonds between the body and the surface. Then how can it push ? Even if we push backwards the ground the friction force must only prevent that if it is due to bond formation

Answer (score 2):

When you walk your muscles bend your body forward with respect to the foot. If you were in zero gravity your upper body would move forward and your foot would move backward but your center of gravity would stay put and there would be no overall motion.

If your foot is on the ground, friction prevents the foot from moving backwards and so you get an overall forward motion. The frictional force is translated through your body into movement of the center of gravity.

That's why it is so hard to walk on ice. If there is no friction the foot would slide backwards and you don't get any net motion.

Answer (score 1):

When we walk or run we apply a pushing force against the ground. The ground applies an equal and opposite reaction force on us. See the free body diagram of a runner below.

The ground reaction force on the runner is resolved into the static friction force parallel to the surface and the reaction force normal to the surface. During portions of running the normal reaction force is greater than the gravitational force on the runner in order to lift the runner off the ground.

The static friction force that the ground applies to the runner propels the runner forward, and is equal and opposite to the parallel force the runner applies to the ground. If there were no static friction force the runner will slip. Note that if the parallel component of the runners pushing force on the ground exceeds the maximum possible static friction force, the runner slips.

The difference between the person shown running and a person walking is the angle $θ$ is greater for the walker. When the person is standing still ($θ=90^0$) and the only forces are the persons weight and the equal and opposite normal reaction force of the ground. There is no pushing force for friction to oppose, and so therefore no friction.

A similar situation applies to the bicycle wheel. If  the pushing force of the tire on the ground exceeds the maximum static friction force between the tire and the ground, the tire will slip. This is what can happen on a sandy road surface.

Hope this helps. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Friction is not an attractive force. Friction is a force which opposes the parallel ("sliding") motion of two surfaces. The force of friction is also proportional to the amount of force pushing the two surfaces together, which is usually the "normal force".

So for the walking case, your weight pulls you down, so the floor pushes up on you. So when the rest of your body tries to push your foot backwards, the friction force prevents your foot from sliding, and you get pushed forwards.

The bicycle is similar. The wheels are moving, and if friction is large enough that the tires do not slide on the ground, the friction force propels you forwards.

Comment: I believe you mean parallel motion of two surfaces. Perpendicular would be away from a surface.

Comment: Haha of course, edited.